# The problem is that transition does not work as it should with the background color

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, transition

**- The code is below -**

I've set  as a push button
The problem is with: transition: all 0.5s;
It works well with the button when the background color is changed with the button color at the same time. (When I do: hover)
But when I press the button it stops working. Background color does not work with: transition: all 0.5s;
  But the color of the text continues to work with him.
I didn't understand where the problem was it only happened when I pressed the button.
Then I gave him this code:

```
#pricing .allplan .plan .btn a:link{
background-color: #eaeafd;
padding: 15px 32px;
border-radius: 40px;
color: #4033ff;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
#pricing .allplan .plan .btn a:visited{color: #4033ff;}
#pricing .allplan .plan .btn a:hover{
background-color:#4033ff;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems, when you click on a button it's not the visited status but the active status that is called (a:active). The second mistake is the order of your properties, the active should be after the hover one if you want to overide a css propertie, because of cascading.

```css
.btn a{
  background-color: #eaeafd;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #4033ff;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.btn a:hover{
  background-color:#4033ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.btn a:active{
  color: #4033ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <a href="#">link</a>
<div>
```

Comment: No, I don't need to be active
I only when I put the mouse button on, but when clicking, there is a problem with the transition. You tried your style and you did not succeed with me. thank you so much